# MongoDB C# BsonRepresentation of an Array of ObjectIds

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, mongodb-.net-driver

I have such scheme of document:

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fbb728d80db260988580e05"),
  "titleFull" : "Foo, Inc",
  "titleShort" : "Foo",
  "countries" : [
     ObjectId("4fba04ef80db260988f8b607"),
     ObjectId("4fba05f880db260988cd5cfd") ],
  "type" : "company"
}
```

And such class in ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API project:

```c#
public class Company
{
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
  public String id { get; set; }
  public String titleFull { get; set; }
  public String titleShort { get; set; }
  //[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
  //public String[] countries { get; set; } — not working
  public ObjectId[] countries { get; set; }
  public String type { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm sending GET request on `/api/countries` I receive JSON document (It's mvc deserialization):

```js
{
  "id": "4fba097e80db2609886ce7f2",
  "titleFull": "Foo, LLC",
  "titleShort": "Foo",
  "countries": [
    {
      "_increment": 16299527
      "_machine": 8444710
      "_pid": 2440
      "_timestamp": 1337591023
    },
    {
      "_increment": 13458685
      "_machine": 8444710
      "_pid": 2440
      "_timestamp": 1337591288
    }
  ],
  "type": "company"
}
```

Is there a way to do JSON response like this:

```js
{
  "id": "4fba097e80db2609886ce7f2",
  "titleFull": "Foo, LLC",
  "titleShort": "Foo",
  "countries": ["4fba04ef80db260988f8b607","4fba05f880db260988cd5cfd"],
  "type": "company"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Note to future readers

Rober Stam wrote in google groups:

> There is a bug in the deserialization code. In the case of an array the [BsonRepresentation] attribute is in fact applied to the items and not the array.
>
> I've created a JIRA ticket for this:
>
> https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-479

So if you have the same issue, please track this ticket.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I'm going to delete my answer as it is incorrect at this time.

Answer (score 0):

In the response instead of use ObjectId for Countries use a Array of string and add the ids that you want to pass in the json response.

public string[] countries { get; set; }

if you use like this the response will be something like this in json

"countries": ["4fba04ef80db260988f8b607","4fba05f880db260988cd5cfd"],

You are using a string already in the id field.

Comment: String in the `id` is the result of deserialization with `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` comment.

Comment: And I can't use Array of `string` because I already have scheme with Array of `ObjectId`s

Comment: And you need to have a array of ObjectId's?

Comment: In MongoDB I would like to have an array of `ObjectId`s, but in application more convenient to receive JSON object with an array of `Strings`

Comment: If you must use the object ID, then you will have to work with it in the json response, or return the array of string in the json response.